# country code in bottle REQUESTS running on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bottle

I'm running bottle on google app engine and would like to make use of X-AppEngine-Country header [doc here..](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Request_Headers) . But nowhere this header is visible in bottle Requests. Any alternative to get this header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access location HTTP headers with bottle using the global `request` object.

```
from bottle import Bottle, request

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/country')
def hello():
  return request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Country')
```

Try it [here](http://bottleae.proppy-samples.appspot.com/country)

Note that these location based headers are only available in production and not in the development environment.